# Unity Collaborate with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, collaboration

When I download a unity collaborate project from the cloud that has vuforia assets the vuforia scripts are not linked and the settings are not set.

Answer (score 0):

Please download vuforia plugin ( sdk)  from unity hub or  [unity archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) .  After installing this,  I hope this will work.

Also don't forget to turn on the ar option from xr in player setting.
Goto player setting -> xr -> on Ar or vuforia